# accept() passing argument 3 of accept make a pointer to integer without a cast

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

`accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&srv,sizeof(srv))` passing argument 3 of accept make a pointer to integer without a cast

I am trying to use accept function but I get this error.
May someone help me ?
I am new in network programming

Comment: Read the [accept man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept). "The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address." That is, the third parameter needs to be a pointer.

Answer (score 4):

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/accept), it says

> The addrlen argument is a value-result argument: the caller must initialize it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.

So, you need something like this (code taken from [bind() man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/bind)):

```
socklen_t peer_addr_size;
peer_addr_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
    cfd = accept(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &peer_addr,
                 &peer_addr_size);
```